# Reinterpret_cast sent data

Tags: c++

The code below is just an example.

`Function1` is a `dllexport`, how do I properly convert/read the value of `data` inside of `Foo2`?

When I print the value, it returns `000001DFA1C501F3`.

```
Function1(PVOID InPassThruBuffer,   ULONG InPassThruSize);

void Foo(std::wstring* data) {


    Function1(&data, sizeof(wchar_t))
}


// ==============================================

typedef struct _REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO_
{
    UCHAR*          UserData;
    ULONG           UserDataSize;
}REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO;

void __stdcall Foo2(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    std::wstring wdata;

    if (inRemoteInfo->UserDataSize == sizeof(wchar_t))
        wdata = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t *>(inRemoteInfo->UserData);


}
```

Comment: `&data` is a `std::wstring**` - definitely not a `wchar_t*`

Comment: Was the data (`_REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO_`) sent between processes ? If so how ?

Comment: in a C interface, especially naming a function parameter buffer you'll probably not pass a pointer to a pointer to a `std::wstring` but the data contained in the `std::wstring`, i.e. something like `Function1(data->c_str(), data->size() + 1)` (or data `Function1(data->c_str(), (data->size() + 1) * sizeof((*data)[0]))` depending on what exactly `Function1` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void Foo(std::wstring* data)
{
    Function1(const_cast<wchar_t*>(data->c_str()), data->size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
    // or, in C++17 and later:
    // Function1(data->data(), data->size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
}

void __stdcall Foo2(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    wchar_t *wdata = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(inRemoteInfo->UserData);
    int wdatalen = inRemoteInfo->UserDataSize / sizeof(wchar_t);
}
```

Or, if `Foo2()` in called in the context of `Function1()` before `Foo()` exits, then you can just pass the `std::wstring*` pointer itself instead:

```cpp
void Foo(std::wstring* data)
{
    Function1(&data, sizeof(data));

    // or, if Function1() does not *copy* the data,
    // merely passes around the provided pointer as-is:
    //
    // Function1(data, sizeof(*data));
}

void __stdcall Foo2(REMOTE_ENTRY_INFO* inRemoteInfo)
{
    std::wstring *wdata = *reinterpret_cast<std::wstring**>(inRemoteInfo->UserData);

    // or:
    // std::wstring *wdata = reinterpret_cast<std::wstring*>(inRemoteInfo->UserData);
}
```